# nhibernate session starts

Tags: nhibernate, session

When I just Create the Factory, It seems to do a lot of work (in the log4net console) when it start without me asking him to do anything. could it be that those are just tests he does for himself?

Comment: Do you have some sort of Database Creator running prior to your app execution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a sessionFactory is an expensive operation.  Typically you only create one sessionFactory at the start of your application and store a cached version for creating your sessions.

Comment: yes yea but is it o.k that he tries a crud query on eached mapped entity when session factory created ?

Comment: It's not making CRUD calls, its building the Static SQL statements for CRUD operations.